# Flask return JWT token when redirecting

Tags: python, flask, jwt, pyjwt

I have been following [this Flask pyjwt](https://realpython.com/blog/python/token-based-authentication-with-flask/#jwt-setup) guide, however my web app is somewhat similar to [Miguel's microblog example](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) that uses `render_template()` and `redirect(url_for(...))` for navigation.

I have implemented an encoding and decoding service in my application, however I do not know how to properly return the encoded JWT token to the user using `redirect()`

My code is as follows:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    username = login_form.username.data
    password = login_form.password.data

    if is_user_valid(username, password):
        return redirect(url_for('home'), auth_service.encode_token(username))
    render_template('login.html', form=login_form)
```

My problem is placing the auth token inside the redirect method causes a page to appear saying "Redirecting... you should be redirected, if not click here", which I do not want. I do not particularly wish to change my redirect methods to something similar to `make_response(jsonify(...))` as I would then need to handle these responses in the front end when this is a simple login page.

**How should I be returning the auth token to the client correctly?**

Answer (score 2):

Typically you attach it to response headers which is what your `redirect` method returns.

```
response = redirect(url_for('home'))
response.headers['X-JWT-TOKEN'] = auth_service.encode_token(username)
return response
```

However, I'm not sure if this is gonna be very useful in your setup when using `render_template`, because you can not easily access these headers on the frontend.

You have two alternatives here:

- Make your login endpoint an API. This way you can return the token for the client-side code to handle and store it somehow.
- Drop the JWT and stick to using sessions. I know that this is not what you expected, but outside of building APIs JWT-based auth is not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a cookie for this.

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    login_form = LoginForm()
    username = login_form.username.data
    password = login_form.password.data

    if request.method == 'POST' and is_user_valid(username, password):
        response = redirect('/')
        response.set_cookie('Authorization',auth_service.encode_token(username))
        return redirect(url_for('home'), )
    render_template('login.html', form=login_form)
```

in your middleware you could do something like this:

```
def token_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        token = None
        if "Authorization" in request.cookies:
            token = request.cookies["Authorization"]
            return f(token, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            redirect(url_for('login', )

    return decorated
```

the home method can than be wrapped with this wrapper:

```
@app.route("/home")
@token_required
def counter_page(token):
    pass # do something with token
```